# Does scipy , python, numpy or pyspark/pandas have the similar function?

Tags: python, r, numpy, pyspark, scipy

We have a R language code using pdf_sum and pdf_percentile to calculate probability density function (PDF)

Now we are thinking if we can use the existing python library to calculate probability density function (PDF) .

Does any library for scipy , python, numpy or pyspark/pandas have the similar function ?

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example of what you're trying to compute? Please provide a [mre] with a minimal input and the matching expected output.

Comment: Are `pdf_sum` and `pdf_percentile` functions from a separate R library?  If so, please provide a link to the library.

Answer (score 2):

[`scipy.stats`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) has a set of functions for most well known statistical distributions.

You can use the `pdf` method of each of those distributions to get the probability density functions.

For instance with the normal and uniform distributions:

```py
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot()

x = np.linspace(-2, 2)

# gaussian with loc=0, scale=1
ax.plot(x, scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, 0, 1), label='normal')
# uniform distribution with loc=-1, scale=2 (= [-1, 1])
ax.plot(x, scipy.stats.uniform.pdf(x, -1, 2), label='uniform')
```

Note that `scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, 0, 1)` can also be written as:

```py
n = scipy.stats.norm(0, 1)
out = n.pdf(x)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scipy.status` module gives you functions for **PDF** calculation, if you want function for  **continuous distributions** you can use `pdf()` method or if you want for **discrete distributions** then you can use `pmf()`. If you want to compare histograms and density estimates `numpy` and `pandas` library would be great!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).